# Remove subsequent occurrences of string in other lines of output

Tags: shell, awk

Having SVN or Git log such as this:

```
2020-02-28 r504 Rename SQL scripts <me>
2020-02-28 r503 Fix for "paginated report" <someone.else>
2020-02-26 r502 Add task in script <me>
2020-02-26 r501 Add environment file <me>
```

I'd like the output to better more readable by getting such an output:

```
2020-02-28 r504 Rename SQL scripts <me>
           r503 Fix for "paginated report" <someone.else>
2020-02-26 r502 Add task in script <me>
           r501 Add environment file <me>
```

(That is, remove the leading date timestamp when it's not the first time it appears.)

How would I best try to do this?

Comment: Write a script in your favorite language.

Comment: That's the question: how should I write an AWK or whatever script able to "suppress" the subsequent output of the same date?

Comment: @user3341592: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? You make it impossible to "grep" your output?

Comment: Honestly : this is a good exercise to *try* to write such a script yourself (which can be an `awk` script if you want to)

Comment: @Dominique. Good point. Though I do think the readability for every day usage is more important. Is there a way to color that part of the text in the background color?  So, that we have both advantages?

Comment: @user3341592: the colouring is determined by the system you're working with: UNIX, Linux, what tool (Putty, SecureCRT, ...), ...? You might need to give more information.

Comment: @Dominique, I'm using Cygwin or WSL on Windows. I know we can reset the color, but I don't know whether there is a way to color in the background's color (to have something "universal")...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this awk script:

```
awk '{
tmp=$1
if ( date == $1 ) {
    $1=sprintf("%" length($1) "s","");
}
date=tmp
print
}'
```

Comment: thanks for coming up with something… Adding that with a pipe at the end of one of my output did not really work. First problem is spacing, maybe because my output is colored. Changing length by 10 above does solve that. Second is that when there are 3 times (or more) the same date (in a row), the date re-appears. Dunno how to solve that.

Comment: @user3341592 I fixed the thing with 3+ in a row.

Comment: Thanks!  Works like a charm.